# Footer in middle of page in different browers

Tags: css, footer

For some reason whenever I add a widget to the footer of my site, it moves to the center of the page - but only in Chrome and Safari. Firefox the footer stays put at the bottom.

The only way I can think to change this is to increase the padding-top size. This puts the footer back at the bottom and looks fine in Safari and Chrome, but obviously looks terrible in Firefox.

What am I doing wrong? [Site link](http://tinyurl.com/m5vt83a)

Footer.php -

```
    <div id="footer">
    <div class="footer">

<?php if( is_front_page() ) { 
echo do_shortcode('[responsive_column_widgets]');
}
?>
</div><!--//footer-->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Style.css -

```
#footer{
margin-top: -90px; /* negative value of footer height. this need to be  */
height: 100px;
clear:both;
padding-top:20px;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
color:#fff;
}
#footer img {
padding:3px; 
margin:3px;
}
```

Comment: Why did this receive a downvote? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your content div in your header div. Place content div after header div. OR Go to style.css of your theme find #header style and remove height which is fixed to 524px. Better one is to have content div out of header div.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Tried it but it doesn't work..

Comment: @SocialMonster See my updated answer..

Comment: Great, that worked! Many thanks! Curious... how does removing the height of the header fix the footer?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code errors, such as the missing `</div>` and `</html>` tags.

See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  katiebagley.com jack  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//katiebagley.com/jack/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Start fixing the code errors and revalidate.

Comment: Great, thank you for this. Didn't realise I had so many